# Manipulate specific columns (sample features) conditional on another column's entries (feature value) using pandas/numpy dataframe

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

my **input** dataframe (shortened) looks like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df_in = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 'a', 3, 4], [6, 7, 'b', 8, 9]],
...                     columns=(['c1', 'c2', 'col', 'c3', 'c4']))
>>> df_in
   c1  c2 col  c3  c4
0   1   2   a   3   4
1   6   7   b   8   9
```

---

It is supposed to be manipulated, i.e.

*if row (sample) in column 'col' (feature) has a specific value (e.g., 'b' here), 
then convert the entries in columns 'c1' and 'c2' in the same row to NumPy.NaNs.*

**Result wanted:**

```
>>> df_out = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 'a', 3, 4], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 8, 9]], 
                         columns=(['c1', 'c2', 'col', 'c3', 'c4']))
>>> df_out
    c1  c2 col  c3  c4
0    1   2   a   3   4
1  NaN NaN   b   8   9
```

---

So far, I managed to get obtain **desired result via the code**

```
>>> dic = {'col' : ['c1', 'c2']}          # auxiliary

>>> b_w = df_in[df_in['col'] == 'b']      # Subset with 'b' in 'col'
>>> b_w = b_w.drop(dic['col'], axis=1)    # ...inject np.nan in 'c1', 'c2'

>>> b_wo = df_in[df_in['col'] != 'b']     # Subset without 'b' in 'col'

>>> df_out = pd.concat([b_w, b_wo])       # Both Subsets together again
>>> df_out
    c1   c2  c3  c4 col
1  NaN  NaN   8   9   b
0  1.0  2.0   3   4   a
```

---

Although I get what I want (the original data consists entirely of floats, don't 
bother the mutation from int to float her), it is a rather inelegant 
snippet of code. And my educated guess is that this could be done faster 
by using the build-in functions from pandas and numpy, but I am unable to manage this.

Any suggestions how to code this in a **fast and efficient** way for daily use? Any help is highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can condition on both the row and col positions to assign values using `loc` which supports both logic indexing and dimension name indexing:

```
df_in.loc[df_in.col == 'b', ['c1', 'c2']] = np.nan

df_in
#    c1  c2  col   c3  c4
# 0 1.0 2.0    a    3   4
# 1 NaN NaN    b    8   9
```

Answer (score 0):

When using **pandas** I would go for the solution provided by @Psidom.

However, for larger datasets it is faster when doing the whole *pandas -> numpy -> pandas* procedure, i.e. *dataframe -> numpy.array -> dataframe* (minus 10% process time for my setup). Without converting back to a dataframe, **numpy** is almost twice as fast for my dataset.

Solution for the question asked:

```
cols, df_out = df_in.columns, df_in.values
for i in [0, 1]:
    df_out[df_out[:, 2] == 'b', i] = np.nan
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df_out, columns=cols)
```